# Conditional rendering of a text Input in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How do you render a textInput conditionally such that when the value `text` in the textInput characters is less than 6, it logs an error when the user clicks the ok button

```
const [text, setText] = useState('')
<TextInput
  style={styles.textInputStyle}
  value={text}
  onChangeText = {(text) => setText(text)}
  placeholder="Text"
  placeholderTextColor="#60605e" />
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
  onPress={() => {setText(text)} }>
  <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>OK</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: What is `pricealert`?

Comment: Please make a working code example for your question, generally speaking you render conditionally by let's say smth like this `{myBool && <div>smth</div>}`

Comment: You don't need conditional rendering for this, your `onPress` handler needs to check the `text` length and log the error if `text.length < 6`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `onPress` callback can manage this. It needs to do a check for `text.length < 6` and then branch based off of the result. It might look like this (I removed the styling logic to showcase the callback):

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  return (
    <>
      <TextInput
         value={text}
         onChangeText = {(text) => setText(text)}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          if(text.length < 6) {
            // Alert user of invalid input
            Alert.alert("Input must be less than 6 characters!") ;
            return;
          }
          // ... continue on to the desired task
        }}
      >
        <Text>OK</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </>
  );
}
```